# How to get stl::list iterator value in C++ debugger

Tags: c++, debugging

How can i see std::list::iterator value in C++ debugger? I use CLion or Xcode, but the only thing i see is memory address, please, see screenshot:

[image]

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::list<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    auto it =  l.begin();
    std::cout << *it;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try adding an expression like `*it` to your watch/expression view.

Answer (score 1):

As you can already see the debugger shows that a std::list 'node' contains pointers to previous and next nodes. It looks like there is nothing else in the node struct but there is in fact a third pointer that immediately follows it in memory. This points to the list element. If you're enough of a masochist you can probably cook up a LLDB synthetic type provider in Python to show the value in addition to prev and next.

I just can't imagine why it was ever considered useful or desirable to hide the thing a list iterator refers to! No doubt there's a really good reason that makes total sense to the brainiacs in charge of C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can see **it** value by two way :

one is print on your cmd.

```
std::cout << *it;
```

Another way is give the **it** value to a pointer:

```
int *ptr = it._Ptr;
```

You should see value in debugger

[image]

Comment: If you need to modify a program in order to debug it, you just need a better debugger.